# ValueError in numpy.fromstring

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert these string values to numpy array of int16 datatype

```
import numpy as np
raw=b''
w="\x01\x02 \x01\x02"
w1="\x01\x03 \x04"
p=w.replace(" ", "")
w1=w1.replace(" ","")
raw +=p
raw +=w1
results = np.fromstring(raw, dtype=np.uint16)
print results
```

I am getting the error as:

```
>File "prj1.py", line 11, in <module>
> results = np.fromstring(raw, dtype=np.uint16)
>ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

How can I convert these strings to numpy arrray with data type as int16?

Comment: What is `len(raw)`?  I'm guessing 7.  `w1` only has 3 bytes (after removing the space).

Comment: in 'w1="\x01\x03 \x04"', you should be adding a second character (`\x00` before `\x04`?). If that is not possible, why don't you do it without replacing the spaces and instead do `resutl = np.fromstring(raw, dtype=int, sep=' ').astype(uint16)`?

Comment: @hpaulj- Yes the len(raw) is 7. But how can I achieve the array of dtype uint16 ?

Comment: @ThomasKühn- I tried that but the resulting array is [0].

Comment: @joel just to make entirely sure, do you want to get an array with 4 elements? Can you give me the output you expect? I'm not quite sure if the \x04 should be the first or second byte.

Comment: @ThomasKühn-I was expecting it to be array of length 4. Thank you:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message states, if `fromstring` is fed binary input data, the data length must be a multiple of the element size. This is also stated in the documentation. In your case, the element size is 2, because a `uint16` is composed of two bytes. However in your second string, `w1`, you only provide 1 byte. One way to solve this problem is to add a leading zero to the smaller number:

```
import numpy as np
raw=b''
w="\x01\x02 \x01\x02"
w1="\x01\x03 \x04"
elements=w.split(' ')+w1.split(' ')
raw=b''.join(['\x00'+e if len(e)==1 else e for e in elements ])
results = np.fromstring(raw, dtype=np.uint16)
print results
```

This outputs:

```
[ 513  513  769 1024]
```

For me this result was surprising. Apparently the bytes are read from left to right (smallest to biggest). I don't know if this is platform specific (I'm on `osx`) or always like this in `numpy`. Anyway, if your desired byte order is from right to left, you can reverse the order like so:

```
raw2=b''.join([e+'\x00' if len(e)==1 else e[1]+e[0] for e in elements])
results2 = np.fromstring(raw2, dtype=np.uint16)
print results2
```

which results in:

```
[258 258 259   4]
```

Comment: Well, the way you generate the strings, where every number is separated by a space, you do know that. If your input is generated in a different way, the solution may have to be adjusted. If you have only binary input that you do not generate yourself at all, you actually cannot solve this problem, as there is no way to know which numbers have one byte and which ones have two ...

Comment: Thankyou :) . But I guess this is useful only when you know the length of the string is 1? But as in the problem I stated here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45042553/can-anyone-help-me-with-the-errors ) the length of the strings are unknown.

Comment: @joel -- see my comment in the other question. In my opinion this question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs :
Raises Value Error : 
If the string is not the correct size to satisfy the requested `dtype` and `count`

You can convert to `uint8`

```
raw = ""
w="\x01\x02 \x01\x02"
w1="\x01\x03 \x04"
p=w.replace(" ", "")
w1=w1.replace(" ","")
raw +=p
raw +=w1
results = np.fromstring(raw, dtype=np.uint8)
print(results)

[1 2 1 2 1 3 4]
```

If you really want to convert to unit16 , you can use `astype`

```
results.astype(np.uint16)

array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4], dtype=uint16)
```